# Powershell to export AD thumbnails to database

Tags: sql, powershell, thumbnails

New to Poweshell. Trying to export AD thumbnails to a database table. I can store the thumbnail as either varbinary or base64 string. The problem I am having is my script is just hanging. I was unable to find any clean examples of exporting to a database. Any help in understanding why this is hanging is most appreciated.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSERVER; Initial 
      Catalog=DBName; Integrated Security=SSPI");
$conn.open();
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true -and passwordneverexpires -eq $false -and  
     sAMAccountName -eq "MyUserName"} -SearchBase 
     "OU=MIS_Staff,OU=People,OU=MyCompany,DC=mydomain,DC=com" -Properties * |
     Where-Object { $_.thumbnailphoto -ne $Null } |
    select name,samaccountname,EmployeeNumber,ThumbNailPhoto;
   foreach ($item in $users) {
    $cmd = $conn.createcommand();
    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT AdPhotos (Username, EmployeeNumber, Image)
       VALUES ('$($item.samaccountname)', '$($item.employeeNumber)', '$($item.thumbnailPhoto)')";
    $cmd.executenonquery(); 
   $conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a database to write this into, but there are a few points I can make without testing.  The first thing I noticed is you're closing the SQL connection on every loop iteration.  It looks like won't get past the first insert.

I did a few other adjustments, mostly so I could play with it:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSERVER; Initial 
      Catalog=DBName; Integrated Security=SSPI")
$conn.open()

# Should you escape the Bools?
$ADFilter   = "Enabled -eq $true -and passwordneverexpires -eq $false -and sAMAccountName -eq 'MyUserName'"
$SearchBase = "OU=MIS_Staff,OU=People,OU=MyCompany,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
$ADProps    = 'EmployeeNumber', 'ThumbNailPhoto'

$Users = 
Get-ADUser -Filter $ADFilter -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties $ADProps |
Where-Object { $_.ThumbNailPhoto } |
Select-Object Name,samAccountName,EmployeeNumber,ThumbNailPhoto

ForEach ( $User in $Users ) 
{
    $cmd = $conn.createcommand()
    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT AdPhotos (Username, EmployeeNumber, Image)
       VALUES ('$($User.samaccountname)', '$($User.employeeNumber)', '$($User.thumbnailPhoto)')"
    $cmd.executenonquery()
}

# Close the connection after the loop:
$conn.close
```

As a general practice, you should only retrieve the properties you need.  I also replaced `$Item` with `$User` which is more of a standard pattern.  I also don't think you need `Select-Object` the code should work fine without it, though I did leave it in the example.

Not sure if this is an issue, but the ThumbNail property is going to return a byte array (`[byte[]]`) in `$cmd.commandText = "..."` that should convert to a string delimited on spaces.  However, you'll probably want to check the SQL data type of the Image column to make sure it can take the data...

Incidentally, there are several ways to use the .Net classes to work with SQL DBs.  My code for such things is a little different but looking at the methods and documentation, what you've done should work.